# Why do semi-positive definite matrices have negative eigenvalues when I use the function torch.eig()?

Tags: pytorch

Why do semi-positive definite matrices have negative eigen values when I use the function `torch.eig()`? How can I resolve this problem?

```
tp1 = torch.tensor([[123., 43, 4], [-23, 44, -1]])
a = torch.mm(tp1.t(), tp1)
eigVals, eigVecs = torch.eig(a, eigenvectors=True)
```

Result for `eigVals` is:

```
tensor([[ 1.7055e+04, 0.0000e+00], [ 2.4053e+03, 0.0000e+00], [-7.5416e-06, 0.0000e+00]])
```

Comment: Looks like a numerical issue since it's so small anyway. Matlab also gives a negative result when single precision is used.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem recently with the determinant of positive-definite matrices (and confirmed it with the eigenvalues).

I can only suggest you to pass to double precision, with all the issues that may arise because of that (memory, etc.).

You can do as:

```
tp1 = torch.DoubleTensor([[123., 43, 4], [-23, 44, -1]])
a = torch.mm(tp1.t(), tp1)
eigVals, eigVecs = torch.eig(a, eigenvectors=True)
```

You can see that by default instantiation the tensor type is `float32` and the result of some operations change.

```
tp1 = torch.DoubleTensor([[123., 43, 4], [-23, 44, -1]])
a = torch.mm(tp1.t(), tp1)
a.det()
tensor(-15.0122)
```

But if you create it as a `DoubleTensor`:

```
a.det()
tensor(-1.2544e-07, dtype=torch.float64)
```

Unfortunately in your case one of the eigenvalues will still be negative but much closer to zero.

```
torch.eig(a, eigenvectors=True)
eigenvalues=tensor([[ 1.7055e+04,  0.0000e+00],
    [ 2.4053e+03,  0.0000e+00],
    [-6.8641e-15,  0.0000e+00]], dtype=torch.float64),
```

Comment: Since the eigen values of a semi-positive definite matrix are non-negative ，and the positive eigen values remain unchanged although changing dtype,I decide to reset the negative eigen value.@Demplo

Comment: I understand, in my experience the frequency of this kind of problem decreases significantly using double. Nonetheless, as you've seen, no guarantee...